# How to maintain the count of active threads - java

Tags: java, multithreading

need help

I have a task count of 250.
I want all these tasks to be done via a fixed no of threads. ex 10
so, I want to feed each thread one task

```
t1 =1
t2=2
.
.
.
```

currently I have written the code in such a way that, among those 10 threads each thread picks one task.
and I will wait till all the 10 threads are done using the `thread.join()`.and then again create 10 threads and feed each thread one task.

#### Problem:

Although some of the threads are finished performing the task. I need to still wait for other threads to complete.
I want to maintain the thread count as 10 through . That is if among 10 threads if one thread finished the task, it can pick another task and similarly others.

any solution?

#### my Code:

```java
for(int i=0;i<finData.size();i++){
      ArrayList<Thread> AllThreads = new ArrayList<>();

      if(i+10 <= finData.size()){
          p=i+10;
      }else{
          p=i+10-finData.size();                            
      } 
                    
     for(int k=i;k<p;k++){
        FeeConfigCheck = new  Thread(new FeeConfigCheck(finData.get(k)));
        AllThreads.add(FeeConfigCheck);
        FeeConfigCheck.start(); 
        Thread.sleep(100);                          
     }  

     for(int h=0;h<AllThreads.size();h++){
        AllThreads.get(h).join();
     }
     if(p<10){
            System.out.println("Pointer----------------"+i);
            break;
     }
     i=p;
     System.out.println("Pointer----------------"+i);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an ExecutorService?

Comment: Surely the number of active threads is just `AllThreads.size() - h`?

Comment: hi @AndyTurner yes i am adding all the threads to a thread list once i start those.That is my 'AllThreads.size()'. Since i am using the 'AlThreads.get(h).join()'. that for loop will terminate only when all the threads are done doing their task. I want to modify my code in such a way that instead of waiting for all the threads to complete. what ever thread is done has to fetch the the next task.

Comment: @RealSkeptic If there is a possibility to do with ExecutorService can u provide any reference or example.It will be helpful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel; this is not neccessary. Java already contains functionality to have a fixed number of threads plus a number of tasks, and then having this fixed number of threads process all the tasks: [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (int k = i; k < p; k++) {
    Runnable r = new FooConfigCheck(finData.get(k));
    pool.submit(r);
}
pool.shutdown();
while (!pool.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) ;
```

That's all you have to do here.

See the javadoc of these classes for the various things you can ask it; how many tasks are in the queue is something you can ask, if you need that information.

EDIT: Added a call to shutdown.

Comment: Thank you very much @rzwitserloot it worked for me .Here is the answer
`ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (int k = 0; k < finData.size(); k++) {
   Runnable r = new FeeConfigCheck(finData.get(k));
         Thread.sleep(100);
    pool.submit(r);
}
pool.shutdown();
while (!pool.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) ;`

Comment: @kichuf1 There shouldn't be a `Thread.sleep()` there. That's just slowing down the submission process. In any case, don't put code in comments. It's unreadable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah i removed the 'Thread.sleep()'. But i have new issue here. The solution provided above fixed the issue but. I am getting a lot is Sync issues. i.e. The for loop is actually not waiting for one thread to finish and then feed the thread.

Comment: find it in below comment . Still 10 count it fed the threads normally but after 10 the loop continued but there is not thread to pic the task. only after one thread finishes i.e among ten threads soon after every thread finishes its task it has to pic the next task

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
int count=0;
while(count<finData.size()){                        
 if (pool instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
    if(((ThreadPoolExecutor) pool).getActiveCount()<20){
        System.out.println("Pointer -----"+count);
        Runnable r = new FeeConfigCheck(finData.get(count));
        pool.submit(r);
        count++;
        Thread.sleep(500);
     }
  }
}
pool.shutdown();
while (!pool.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) ;
```

This Worked for me. The pointer was keep on incrementing even when all threads are busy. So i used the getActiveCount() to know the number of active threads. this way i was able to feed the thread whenever it completed its task.Thanks all for the help. :)